# R how to format date for an element of a list

Tags: r, date

This is what I want to do:

First, I randomly generate a sequence of dates.
Then, I assign the earliest date to the variable.

```
site_start<-list()
  for(i in 1:l0){
    for(j in 1:10){
      date<-seq.Date(from="1900-01-01",to="2000-01-01",by=week)
      site_start[[i]][j]<-sample(date,1)
    }
  }
```

Now, let us assume the date variable is correctly generated. The reason I say this is because in my real case, I acquired the date variable from dozens of other steps that is irrelevant here.

My question is, why the site_start[[i]][j] I generated, kept on coming out as POSIXct, and R requires me to provide 'origin'? I format it with origin of 1970-01-01, it is still a numeric date, such as 15600. I simply don't know how to format this number anymore.

Any help is appreciated!!

W

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this vectorized approach:

```
date.pool <- seq(from=as.Date("1900-01-01"), to=as.Date("2000-01-01"), by="1 week")
site_start <- replicate(10, sample(date.pool, 10, rep=T), simplify=F)
```

This produces a list with 10 items, each of which is a 10 length vector with random dates pulled from `date.pool`.  Here are the first two items (`site_start[1:2]`):

```
[[1]]
 [1] "1969-09-15" "1955-10-10" "1959-04-13" "1992-02-10" "1905-07-31" "1901-09-23"
 [7] "1926-10-18" "1959-06-01" "1924-06-02" "1906-05-14"

[[2]]
 [1] "1979-01-01" "1998-02-23" "1929-09-02" "1968-07-01" "1924-03-17" "1914-11-02"
 [7] "1928-02-13" "1937-10-25" "1915-02-08" "1974-05-06"
```

Comment: A small correction: `date.pool` inside `sample()`, not `date`.

Comment: @Rcoster, thanks.  Yet another reason why one should clear their workspace before doing anything...

Comment: @Rcoster, I tried to used replicate(), but now, I need to put the min(date) into site_start[[g]][h]. date is array object of many dates. Instead of puting POSXIct into the element of the list, it 'replicate' nothing but zero into it. Do you know how to put a date into an element of list?

Comment: @user3166055, you need to provide more details on the structure of your `date` object.  Do you just want the smallest date to be put into `site_start[[x]][y]`?  This means you'll have the same date for every value in `site_start`.  Can you clarify what you expect `site_start` to contain?

Comment: @BrodieG, can you try this: a<-list()     a[[1]][1]<-as.Date("1991-01-01", origin="1970-01-01"). In my machine, a[[1]][1] is still a numeric object, not a date object. I need it to be a date object, in order to do some math with the date.

Comment: @user3166055, your code produces an error.  If I do this: `a<-list(numeric()); a[[1]][1] <- as.Date("1991-01-01", origin="1970-01-01")` then it results in a number.  The problem is you are inserting a date into a numeric vector.  This does what I think you expect `a <- list(as.Date(numeric(), origin="1970-01-01")); a[[1]][1] <- as.Date("1991-01-01")`.  Note how I initialized the vector inside `a` to be of date type.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, when I have had to grab the oldest or most-recent entry I will use arrange. E.g.,

```
# read dataset
enforce <- read.csv(paste(input.dir, "provider_enforcement.csv", sep="/"))

# use lubridate package to parse date format
enforce$SNAPSHOT_DATE <- mdy_hm(enforce$SNAPSHOT_DATE)

# this function sorts a data.frame and returns a data.frame with one row containing the most recent SNAPSHOT
MostRecent <- function(data) {
  return(arrange(data, SNAPSHOT_DATE, decreasing=TRUE)[1, ])
}

# use plyr to apply MostRecent to my dataset for each provider
enforce <- ddply(enforce, .(PROVIDER_IDNO), MostRecent)
```